# Getting System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been running a workbook with a few macros in it for a couple of years, and I've suddenly started getting this error thrown at me for some navigational buttons (shapes linked to macros that are simply `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_name").Activate`).

Other Macros within the workbook seem to work OK, but I can't get into the VBA editor to see any of the code anymore - I get to the VBA interface, but when I go to open the Module, nothing happens.

And to cap it all off, when I try to save the workbook, I'm just getting an error saying 'Document not saved'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. I opened the VBA code module and then selected Debug then Compile VBAProject. I then closed the Visual Basic Editor and the error seems to have been resolved. Have only had the issue the once so can't be 100% sure it will work in every instance but worth a go.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you open a backup copy of this file (if you have one), export the broken module and then in your current file, remove the broken module and import the clean version.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in a file that was drawing data from an external source and saving itself automatically every minute. What worked for us was just replacing the entire file with a backup from 2 days ago.

We also had the "Document Not Saved" error, which was solved by upgrading the file from .xls to .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I have fought with this error for days after saving a improved copy of my worksheet. What worked to me was, I followed the instructions from this link on Microsoft site (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/system-error-h80070057-2147024809-the-parameter-is/426f24ca-5f4b-42c4-956b-d0ecf977ca98), then I zipped all old files that could be linked and deleted the source files from my computer. I reopened the file and clicked to update file. Since it did not found the link to update, a window with some options was displayed then I hit "Break Link". The file started working properly and my worksheet is working fine